# What are the difference between TextBlob and NLTK classifiers?

Tags: nlp, nltk

I am implementing a text classifier and I found classifiers with NLTK and TextBlob. What are the differences between classifiers of those packages?
for example is there a difference between Textblob's NaiveBayesClassifier and Nltk's one?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is absolutely no difference in implementation because Textblob's classifiers are literally just a wrapper around NLTK classifiers.

This is very simple to see from the Textblob [source code](https://github.com/sloria/TextBlob/blob/dev/textblob/classifiers.py#L188).

For example, `textblob.classifiers.NaiveBayesClassifier` wraps `nltk.classify.NaiveBayesClassifier`, and the first line of its docstring is:

> A classifier based on the Naive Bayes algorithm, as implemented in NLTK.